# how to dump data to the database at startup

Tags: flask, docker, flask-sqlalchemy, docker-compose

I have a flask application, and when it spins up, it needs to dump data to the database. The datafiles are each about 100MB, and currently there are three of them, but soon there will be ~15.

```
@app.before_first_request
def populateDB():
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=["not relevant"])
        OCRs = [dict(row.items()) for row in reader]
        db.engine.execute(OpenChromatinRegion.__table__.insert(), OCRs)
```

I have a function called populateDB which works, so long as the file is very small (300 rows). When I go to run it on any of the large files:

```
[2016-05-11 23:22:09 +0000] [7] [INFO] working on datafile MCF7-all.fdr0.01TF_anno.txt
[2016-05-11 23:22:24 +0000] [7] [INFO] Datafile MCF7-all.fdr0.01TF_anno.txt properly configured in memory
[2016-05-11 23:22:39 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7)
[2016-05-11 23:22:41 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

And then it just hangs.

Is there a better way of going about this, or some way of not failing? Perhaps doing it incrementally rather than trying to dump 100MB at once?

-- UPDATE --

I tried incrementally, in 1000-row chunks, and although it got through a couple such chunks, the worker still timed out.

So my current questions are: 
 - if I were to use celery what would that look like?
 - would alembic's op.bulk_insert do this better?

-- UPDATE 2 --

Tried using Flask-Script, which didn't work either.

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from app import app, db
from models import *
manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def populateDB():
    (same function as above)
```

The worked still timed out. Might this have anything to do with Docker? I'm using [this project as my base](https://github.com/realpython/orchestrating-docker).

-- UPDATE 3 --

Strangely, I got this to work locally for one file by `db.session.add()`, `db.session.commit()` for each example. But that seems to be the slowest way of going about it, per [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow). That solution also doesn't work remotely, on digitalocean. I think this might have to do with the memory-pressure. I get through about 1,750,000 rows before it crashes.

-- UPDATE 4 --

After the machine dies, I run `dmesg` and the output reveals:

```
[ 2323.138921] Out of memory: Kill process 6578 (python) score 843 or sacrifice child
```

So this is a memory issue after all. But I believe the database isn't in memory, it's on disk, so what is taking up all the memory? What part of this eats through all the gigabytes of memory, or does docker limit it to less than that? (note, instead of the function above, I'm putting things in the database incrementally, in 10k row chunks.

-- UPDATE 5 --

I moved to a ludicrously big VM and the error went away. But now it still fails when I go to query the database with 1000 keys at once. All it says is "worker killed". The logs don't seem to have any relevant information, making this debugging difficult and frustrating.

I looked at `docker stats <container>` and it seems the memory pressure is at 10%, which should be low enough.

What don't I understand about docker? Why is it arbitrarily killing my containers?

-- UPDATE 6 --

I think the scope of this question has moved too much. It seems like there may have been two separate issues: not enough memory to insert everything into the database previously, and now the queries are timing out. WORKER TIMEOUT I think is actually a message from gunicorn. I'm going to open a new question about gunicorn timeouts and sqlalchemy queries.

If someone finds similar issues in the future, the way I got through not being able to add everything is just increasing the size of the VM. Seems like it should be able to run on a smaller VM, but I guess you do what you can.

Comment: this might be useful for you http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/

Comment: I don't really understand: With flask-sqlalchemy, the two are tied, right? 
`app = Flask(__name__)`;
`db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

Comment: to handle the task appropriately, without your program hanging that is, look into using http://www.celeryproject.org/

Comment: aha! I think that's what I've been looking for but didn't know how to ask for.

Comment: I don't understand. The worker loads a couple thousand rows into the database and then dies. Not sure why.

Comment: How would you do that? Would you add an answer to this question? That might help clarify what you mean. Note: I'm using docker: https://github.com/realpython/orchestrating-docker

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, a better approach would be to use an asynchronous task queue alongside flask since you want to your application to be free to respond to client requests.

as mentioned in my above comment, celery could be an option. (http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: What if you don't need it to be free to handle requests, since you only do this at setup time? (Is celery still the best way of going about this?) I'd rather have just a few lines of python that take a long time. Right now I'm putting things in the db in 1000-row chunks and it seems to be working, albeit slowly.

Comment: why even use flask in that case? why not just run a python script to do the job? is there a particular reason you are using flask? maybe you can provide more context. why don't you use an FTP ?  i thought you wanted to avoid having your program hang (" some way of not failing?") (i dont mean to be rude, just loaded more questions =P)

Comment: So the application needs to do complex lookups in these files and compute statistics on rows in the files. But the files only change every couple of months. So I'd like to have the application start, load the files into Postgres, and then begin serving the analytics on those files. But loading is being harder than I'd imagined.